# hive hbase integration timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I would like to store table into HBase using Hive (hive hbase integration )
My table contains a field typed TIMESTAMP (like DATE)
I've done some research and i discovered that TIMESTAMP is not supported by HBASE, some what should I do?

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating dat at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:83) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:529) ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] 
at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:185) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyTimestamp.init(LazyTimestamp.java:74) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct.uncheckedGetField(LazyStruct.java:219) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct.getField(LazyStruct.java:192) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.objectinspector.LazySimpleStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazySimpleStructObjectInspector.java:188) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:98) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to convert the `TIMESTAMP` into a `STRING`, `INT`, or `FLOAT`. This will have the unfortunate side effect of giving up Hive's built in `TIMESTAMP` support. Due to this you will lose

- Read time checks to make sure your column contains a valid `TIMESTAMP`
- The ability to transparently use `TIMESTAMPS`s of different formats
- The use of Hive UDFs which operate on `TIMESTAMP`s.

The first two losses are mitigated if you choose a single format for your own timestamps and stick to it. The last is not a huge loss because [only two Hive date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) actually operate on `TIMESTAMP`s. Most of them operate on `STRING`s. If you aboslutely needed `from_utc_timestamp` and `from_utc_timestamp`, you can write your own UDF.

If you go with `STRING` and only need the date, I would go with a `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If you need the time as well go with `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]` if you need partial second timestamps. This format also is also consistent with how Hive expects `TIMESTAMP`s and is the form required for most Hive date functions.

If you with `INT` you again have a couple of options. If only the date is important, `YYYYMMDD` fits in with the "basic" format of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (This is a form I've personally used and found convenient when I didn't need to perform any date operations on the column). If the time is also important, go with `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`. This an [acceptable variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) for the basic form of ISO 8601 for date time. If you need fractional second timing, then use a `FLOAT` and the form `YYYYMMDDhhmmss.fffffffff`. Note that neither of these forms is consitent with how Hive expects integer or floating point `TIMESTAMP`s.

If the concept of calendar dates and time of day isn't important at all, then using an `INT` as a Unix timestamp is probably the easiest, or a `FLOAT` if you also need fractional seconds. This form is consistent  with how Hive expects `TIMESTAMP`s.